# Assign two variables in one pass with awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have a log which every minute receives the following data:

```
ID: Unit3443 IP: 192.168.1.1 MAC: 00:20:c0:04:e8:ab
ID: Unit2222 IP: 192.168.2.2 MAC: 00:40:c0:05:e8:bc
```

I grab the last line with tail -1 /File

Is it possible to assign both of those entries to variable in one swoop?  Currently I have

```
UnitID=`tail -1 $File|awk '{print $1}'`
UnitIP=`tail -1 $File|awk '{print $2}'`
```

This works but it requires the file to be read twice and my concern is during the second read the output of tail -1 will no longer be the same.

Is it possible to assign both these variables in one read of the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another alternative instead of using `read` suggested by @PesaThe would be to do the `tail` in one go and use the result twice in order to avoid problems when the file changes between `tail`s.

```
LINE="$(tail -1 "$File")"
UnitID="$(echo "$LINE" | awk '{print $1}')"
UnitIP="$(echo "$LINE" | awk '{print $2}')"
```

Note: I've also changed the sample to use `$()` instead of backticks - works the same way, but easier to get right.

Answer (score 2):

```
arr=( $(tail -1 "$file" | awk '{print $1, $2}') )
UnitID=${arr[0]}
UnitIP=${arr[1]}
```

or:

```
id=0
ip=1
unit=( $(tail -1 "$file" | awk '{print $1, $2}') )
echo "${unit[id]}"
echo "${unit[ip]}"
```

or:

```
line=$(tail -1 "$file" | awk '{print $1, $2}')
UnitID="${line% *}"
UnitIP="${line#* }"
```

Comment: You should consider using `set -f`, just in case :).

Comment: Or use `readarray -t arr < <(tail -f "$file" | awk -v OFS="\n" '{print $1,$2}'`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `read` builtin instead of `awk`:

```
IFS=$' \t' read -r Unit{ID,IP} _ <<< "$(tail -1 "$file")"
```

```
$ declare -p Unit{ID,IP}
declare -- UnitID="Unit2222"
declare -- UnitIP="192.168.2.2"
```

---

Or if your input file really follows the updated format (I don't see how your original code could work):

```
IFS=$' \t' read -r _ UnitID _ UnitIP _ <<< "$(tail -1 "$file")"
```

Comment: this worked but I should have been more clear.  The file it reads from has other information in addition to the unit and ip.  For example; ID: Unit3443 IP: 192.168.1.1 | MAC: 00:20:c0:04:e8:ab

Comment: @teamg Please include the actual input in your question if this is still not working.

Comment: @ PesaThe, it won't let me edit my original question.

Comment: Try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52282779/edit). Anyway, if your original `awk` works, the `read` as of now should work too.

Comment: To handle the "ID:" and "IP" words, you want `read -r _ id _ ip _ <<<"$line"`

Comment: @glennjackman OP changed the input format and if it really looks like it does now, I have a hard time believing his `awk` commands work.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
read UnitID UnitIP < <(awk 'END{print $2, $4}' file)
```

**Test Result**

```
echo $UnitID
Unit2222
echo $UnitIP
192.168.2.2
```

---

As @EdMorton kindly points out in the comments, not all `awk` variants retain the $0..$NF variables into the `END` section, so the following is hopefully more widely applicable:

```
read UnitID UnitIP < <(awk '{a=$2; b=$4} END{print a,b}' file)
```

Comment: The values of $2, $4, etc. (inc. $0) in the END section are undefined by POSIX. With some awks they'll contain the value of the last line read, with others they'll be zero-or-null. To avoid undefined behavior you have to do `awk '{a=$2; b=$4} END{print a, b}'` or `awk '{split($0,f)} END{print f[1], f[2]}'` or similar. Or just state which awks this will work in, e.g. gawk.